# How to use the homology version of Whitehead theorem to prove this question?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a CW-complex, and $A$ a contractible subcomplex. Prove that the quotient map $X \rightarrow X/A $ is a homotopy equivalence.

I got a hint to use the homology version of Whitehead theorem to prove this question. but I have 2 versions in AT, they are given below:

> [image] 
>   [image]

But I do not know which to use and how to use, could anyone help me in this please?

Comment: OMG you don't need this elaborate stuff. Just attach a cone over subspace $A$ and observe the result.

Comment: I do not understand you @GregoryG could say more details please and why I need not use the hint mentioned?

Comment: Because if you attach a cone over $A$ you obtain a space homotopy equivalent to $X,$ while contraction of the cone $CA$ gives you a map to $X/A.$ It is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Gregory's point is backed up by the fact that the statement you wish to prove is in chapter 0 of Hatcher, while the statement you want to use to prove it is in chapter 4. Probably a 350 page gap between those.

Comment: Check out Hatcher Proposition 0.17

Comment: @William and what is the relation  homotopy extension property and $X$ being CW complex?

Comment: Proposition 0.16 says that if $(X,A)$ is a CW pair then $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property.

Comment: I wanted to add that this fact you want to prove holds for any spaces (not just simply connected ones), while Whitehead theorem applies only to simply connected ones. (There is a version for non-simply connected but it is hard (you can find it in McCleary's book chapter $ 8^{bis}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : let $x\in A$ be a point such that there is a homotopy between $id_A$ and the constant map at $x$. You can extend the homotopy between $i:A\to X$ (the inclusion) and $x: A\to X$ to $X$ to get a map $X\to X$ that is constant on $A$, and which is homotopic to $id_X$.